# Show dyadic transpose property $(a \otimes b)^T = b \otimes a$

Tags: proof-writing, tensor-products, tensors

I want to prove that

> $$(a \otimes b)^T = b \otimes a$$ where $\otimes$ is the dyadic product

I think I should just apply the definition. So let $a,b,u,v$ vectors:

$$u \cdot (a \otimes b)^T v=(a \otimes b) u \cdot v = (b \cdot u) a \cdot v$$

Now I don't know how to arrange the terms in order to get the thesis. Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can go directly by calculations

Let $(a,b) \in \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$ Then the dyadic product will be as following :

$a \otimes b = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 b_1 && a_1 b_2 && ... && a_1 b_n \\ a_2 b_1 && a_2 b_2 && ... && a_2 b_n\\ . && . &&&&.\\. &&  && .&&. \\a_nb_1 && a_n b_2 &&...&& a_n b_n   \end{bmatrix}$ $........(1)$

The transpose will be

$(a \otimes b)^T =\begin{bmatrix} a_1 b_1 && a_2 b_1 && ... && a_n b_1 \\ a_1 b_2 && a_2 b_2 && ... && a_n b_2\\ . && . &&&&.\\. &&  && .&&. \\a_1 b_n && a_2 b_n &&...&& a_n b_n   \end{bmatrix}$

Since multiplication of scalars is commutative, then we can have $a_i b_j = b_j a_i$. Let's use this property inside the transposed matrix :

$(a \otimes b)^T =\begin{bmatrix} a_1 b_1 && a_2 b_1 && ... && a_n b_1 \\ a_1 b_2 && a_2 b_2 && ... && a_n b_2\\ . && . &&&&.\\. &&  && .&&. \\a_1 b_n && a_2 b_n &&...&& a_n b_n   \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 a_1 && b_1 a_2 && ... && b_1 a_n \\ b_2 a_1  && b_2 a_2 && ... && b_2 a_n\\ . && . &&&&.\\. &&  && .&&. \\b_n a_1  && b_n a_2 &&...&& a_n b_n   \end{bmatrix}$ $........(2)$

If you compare $(2)$ with $(1)$ (which is the definition of a dyadic product), you'll notice that $(2)$ is nothing more than $ b \otimes a$.

Hence, the proof.

$(a \otimes b)^T = b \otimes a$ .

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. However, I was trying to prove it using the definition of "transpose of a tensor".

Answer (score 1):

If you assume basic matrix algebra identifies known, then it simply follows from the general property of transposing the product of two matrices $\left(\mathbf{AB}\right)^{\operatorname{T}} = \mathbf{B}^{\operatorname{T}}\mathbf{A}^{\operatorname{T}}$ and the fact that

$a \otimes b $ is the same as $ab^{\operatorname{T}}$ (as a product of two matrices) i.e.

$\begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & ... & b_n\end{pmatrix}.$

Therefore $(a \otimes b)^{\operatorname{T}} = (ab^{\operatorname{T}})^{\operatorname{T}} = (b^{\operatorname{T}})^{\operatorname{T}} a^{\operatorname{T}} = ba^{\operatorname{T}} = b \otimes a$. (We also used the fact that matrix transpose is a self-inverse operation $\left(\mathbf{A}^{\operatorname{T}}\right)^{\operatorname{T}}=\mathbf{A}$.)

Comment: N.B. I think you're not asking about higher order tensors here since you said "dyadic". If you want higher order see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.1503.pdf There's more than one way to transpose a 3-order tensor.